# Debug show the updade formBean but the JSP not updated in Struts 1

Tags: jsp, redirect, struts, forward

I have an action Struts 1 that forward to JSP with input data and a select option of object. I want when I change the the select option the date in same JSP change also. I follow the debug mode, the form bean takes the updated value but in display JSP keep the old data ?

**THE JSP :**

```
    <table width="90%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3"
            align="center">
            <tr>
                <td width="22%" class="TableInfo"><bean:message
                        bundle="drive" key="etiquette.form.support" /></td>
                <td width="40%" class="TableInfo"><span class="TabData">
                              <html:select name="colisageForm" property="code"  styleId="mySelect" onchange="submitGetSupport('${root}/getSupportAction.do?methode=getSupport');" >
                              <html:option value="0">--Select Support--</html:option>
                              <html:optionsCollection name="colisageForm"
                                property="listSupport" label="libelle" value="code"  />
                             </html:select>
                </span></td>
           </tr>
            
            <!-- debut ce code cause un probleme quon on clique sur le button retour / CODE A ENLEVER  
            <tr>
                <td width="22%" class="TableInfo"><bean:message
                        bundle="drive" key="etiquette.form.support" /></td>
                <td width="40%" class="TableInfo"><span class="TabData">
                              <html:select name="colisageForm" property="listSupport" styleId="mySelect1" onchange="charge1();">
                              <logic:iterate  id ="supp" name="colisageForm" property="listSupport" indexId="numIndex">
                                 <option value="${numIndex}"><bean:write name="supp" property="libelle"  /></option>
                              </logic:iterate>
                     </html:select>
                </span></td>
            </tr>     -->
            
             <!-- fin -->
    
 
 <nested:present  name="colisageForm" property="supportCommande"  > 
<!--    <bean:define  id="supportCommande" name="colisageForm" property="listSupport[0]" ></bean:define> -->
    ${supportCommande.code }
    <tbody id="dimSupport"  >
     
          <tr>
             <td width="40%" class="ChampTexteLibelle"><bean:message key="etiquette.form.quantite" bundle="drive"/> </td>
              <td width="20%" class="TabData"><nested:text  name="supportCommande" property="quantite" styleClass="ChampTexte" size="1" maxlength="4"   /></td>
            <td width="40%" class="ChampTexteLibelle"><bean:message key="etiquette.form.longueur" bundle="drive"/> </td>
              <td width="20%" class="TabData"><nested:text  name="supportCommande" property="longueur" styleClass="ChampTexte" size="1" maxlength="4"   /></td>
            
           </tr>
            <tr>
             <td width="40%" class="ChampTexteLibelle"><bean:message key="etiquette.form.largeur" bundle="drive"/> :</td>
              <td width="20%" class="TabData"><nested:text  name="supportCommande" property="largeur" styleClass="ChampTexte" size="1" maxlength="4"   /></td>
            <td width="40%" class="ChampTexteLibelle"><bean:message key="etiquette.form.hauteur" bundle="drive"/> :</td>
              <td width="20%" class="TabData"><nested:text  name="supportCommande" property="hauteur" styleClass="ChampTexte" size="1" maxlength="4"   /></td>
            
           </tr>

           
            <tr>
             <td width="40%" class="ChampTexteLibelle"><bean:message key="etiquette.form.poids" bundle="drive"/> :</td>
              <td width="20%" class="TabData"><nested:text  name="supportCommande" property="poids" styleClass="ChampTexte" size="1" maxlength="4"   /></td>
           
             
           </tr>
           
    </tbody> 
  
  
 
 </nested:present>         
</table>
```

**THE ACTION:**

```
public ActionForward getSupport(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        ColisageForm cf = (ColisageForm) form;
        ActionForward forward = mapping.getInputForward();
        // forward.setRedirect(true);
        String code = cf.getCode();
        SupportCommande supportCommande = new SupportCommande();
        ArrayList<SupportCommande> list = cf.getListSupport();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

            if (code.equals(list.get(i).getCode())) {
                supportCommande = list.get(i);

            }

        }
        // request.setAttribute("sc", supportCommande);
        cf.setSupportCommande(supportCommande);
        // return mapping.findForward("resterSupportCommande");

        // return mapping.findForward("resterSupportCommande");
        return forward;

    }
```

**THE BEANFORM:**

```
package com.brico.depot.drive.form;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping;

import com.brico.depot.bapi.DriveBapi;
import com.brico.depot.drive.CommandeDrive;
import com.brico.depot.drive.DriveEcranNumero;
import com.brico.depot.drive.StatutCommande;
import com.brico.depot.drive.SupportCommande;
import com.brico.depot.logistique.Rayon;
import com.brico.depot.session.UserBean;

public class ColisageForm extends ActionForm {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private UserBean user;
    private DriveBapi driveBapi;
    private String numCommande;
    private String statut;
    private String code;
    private String quantite;

    private String rayon;
    private String dateDebut;
    private String dateFin;
    private String buttLbl;
    private ArrayList<StatutCommande> statutList = null;
    private ArrayList<Rayon> listRayons;
    private ArrayList<CommandeDrive> listCommandes;
    private ArrayList<SupportCommande> listSupport = null;
    private SupportCommande supportCommande = null;

    public String getButtLbl() {
        return buttLbl;
    }

    public void setButtLbl(String buttLbl) {
        this.buttLbl = buttLbl;
    }

    /**
     * Retourne la liste de statut de l'ecran Preparer
     *
     * @return Liste des statut pour l'ecran Preparer
     */
    public ArrayList<StatutCommande> getStatutList() {
        driveBapi = new DriveBapi(user);
        if (this.statutList == null) {
            statutList = (ArrayList<StatutCommande>) driveBapi.getListStatuts(DriveEcranNumero.ECRAN_COLISAGE);

            if (statutList != null && statutList.size() > 0) {
                Set<StatutCommande> statutListDedoublonnee = new HashSet<StatutCommande>(statutList);
                statutList = new ArrayList<StatutCommande>(statutListDedoublonnee);
            }
        }
        return statutList;
    }

    public void setStatutList(ArrayList<StatutCommande> statutList) {
        this.statutList = statutList;
    }

    public ArrayList<Rayon> getListRayons() {
        return listRayons;
    }

    public void setListRayons(ArrayList<Rayon> listRayons) {
        this.listRayons = listRayons;
    }

    public String getNumCommande() {
        return numCommande;
    }

    public void setNumCommande(String numCommande) {
        this.numCommande = numCommande;
    }

    public String getStatut() {
        return statut;
    }

    public void setStatut(String statut) {
        this.statut = statut;
    }

    public String getRayon() {
        return rayon;
    }

    public void setRayon(String rayon) {
        this.rayon = rayon;
    }

    public String getDateDebut() {
        return dateDebut;
    }

    public void setDateDebut(String dateDebut) {
        this.dateDebut = dateDebut;
    }

    public String getDateFin() {
        return dateFin;
    }

    public void setDateFin(String dateFin) {
        this.dateFin = dateFin;
    }

    public ArrayList<CommandeDrive> getListCommandes() {
        return listCommandes;
    }

    public void setListCommandes(ArrayList<CommandeDrive> listCommandes) {
        this.listCommandes = listCommandes;
    }

    public ArrayList<SupportCommande> getListSupport() {

        return listSupport;
    }

    public void setListSupport(ArrayList<SupportCommande> listSupport) {
        this.listSupport = listSupport;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getQuantite() {
        return quantite;
    }

    public void setQuantite(String quantite) {
        this.quantite = quantite;
    }

    public SupportCommande getSupportCommande() {
        return supportCommande;
    }

    public void setSupportCommande(SupportCommande supportCommande) {
        this.supportCommande = supportCommande;
    }

    /**
     * Recupere le User de la session
     * 
     * @param mapping
     *            ActionMapping
     * @param request
     *            parametre de la request
     */
    public void reset(ActionMapping mapping, HttpServletRequest request) {
        user = (UserBean) request.getSession(true).getAttribute("USERBEAN");
        this.listCommandes = null;

        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        this.dateDebut = formatter.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        this.dateFin = "31/12/9999";
        this.supportCommande = null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `reset()` method is invoked for any action that reference a form bean.

You can see in the `struts-config.xml` if action is configured to use a form or not if it has a `name` attribute.

If it has a name attribute  but doesn't have `scope` attribute, the default scope is a session scope.

Each time you invoke an action that pick up the form bean from the `session` scope and initializes it with `reset()` method. Then it calls `execute()` where you can modify the value.

If you didn't modify the form with a value after it resettled then it will keep the old value. If you want the new value to be set always use empty value to the property in the `reset()` method.